# How to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 serverside support for my app (hosted on AWS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, tls1.2

I need to work on a nodejs application. The code is using http.createServer() method to create a server. The ssl configurations are taken care at a higher layer than the application code, that's why the code does not use https object with certificate options. I need to disable the support for TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 from this application.
How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: "The ssl configurations are taken care at a higher layer than the application code" & " I need to disable the support for TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 from this application" How you turn that off on the "higher layer" ?! Is this "higher level" nginx/apache as reverse proxy? You need to provide more information about your application.

Comment: It is public network loadbalancer in aws.

Comment: Then do it exactly there.

Comment: This is my first time really working in aws.The infrastructure is created with a CDK code. Do you know if there is some property that I can configure this with?

Comment: No, i dont know. I have no clue how your application stack looks like and you didnt mention that in your question. I would suggest that you try to understand how AWS & the services you use are working. Neither i know what "CDK" code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Marc was right to say that it should be done where the SSL configuration is done.
Basically, the ssl configuration was done manually from the AWS console (In the load balancers, there is an option to add TLS listeners). I just changed the Security Policy for the HTTPS listener and used the recommended latest one and it worked.